# mkvirtualenv in current directory (windows)

Tags: virtual-environment

I am working on a Windows (10) environment using command prompt.  I created a project directory here c:\users\myproject.  In command prompt, I type

```
C:\users\myproject>mkvirtualenv myenv .
     virtuanenv "." already exists
```

If I leave out the "." at the end of the command, it creates a virtual environment in C:\users\Envs\ directory.

How do I create a virtual environment in my project directory itself?

Answer (score 7):

You have to set the `WORKON_HOME` environment variable name and value.

- The name is simply: `WORKON_HOME`
- The value is the path where you want your virtual env directory to be created when you type `mkvirtualenv venv`

"venv" above is nothing special; it's just a name you choose. If you don't specify the `WORKON_HOME` variable, when you run `mkvirtualenv venv` on Windows, a directory named `%USERPROFILE%\Envs` where `%USERPROFILE%` translates to `C:\Users\your.name`.

See my [more verbose, step-by-step answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47705468/1577947).