# Setting up virtual environment on network drive for Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, virtualenvwrapper

I have a project (non-production, not distributed) on a home computer that I want to move to my NAS for editing on multiple Windows computers. I have copied the folder to the NAS, created the requirements.txt file, changed the command prompt to the network drive, and tried each of the following.

```
mkvirtualenv -a "\\NAS\Coding\venv" -r "\\NAS\Coding\local-project\requirements.txt" venv-local-project
mkvirtualenv -r "\\NAS\Coding\local-project\requirements.txt" venv-local-project
mkvirtualenv venv-local-project
virtualenv venv-local-project
```

No matter what I did with the command, it would create the virtual environment on C:.

```
"X:\venv-local-project" is now the project directory for
virtualenv "C:\Users\My Name\Envs\venv-local-project"
```

So, based on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47705468/11792868, I added the environmental variable WORKON_HOME and set the path to the NAS folder as its value.

Now, when I try running the same commands, I get this error:

```
OSError: [WinError 4390] The file or directory is not a reparse point: 'c:\\python\\python.exe' -> '\\\\NAS\\Coding\\venv\\venv-local-project\\Scripts\\python.exe'
```

Any suggestions on what I need to do to get this to work or how I go about setting up the virtual environment on the network drive would be greatly appreciated. Eventually, I would like to do all of the programming on the network drive.

Comment: Try to mount the network dive to a drive, so for example `Y:` points to `\\NAS\Coding` and create the venv on drive `Y`. Most often the UNC paths cause errors and problems.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer Unfortunately, I get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but you cannot do this with virtualenv as it is meant for development in your local system. 
[Stackoverflow T1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225853/relocating-virtual-environment-project-from-local-to-server-flask-project-hav)
[Stackoverflow T2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60607757/setting-up-virtual-environment-on-network-drive-for-windows-10)

What I would do is use `pip freeze` and create `requirements.txt` file and create virtualenv in all the local computers and use that virtualenv terminal to access NAS and run it. If there are any alternative solutions,I am welcoming it

Comment: Will there be any problem with different computers with different virtualenvs editing the same script at different times?

Comment: If editing is involved by multiple people on the same resource, it would behave the same way a file opened in local computer in multiple IDE and your editing in every IDE. Not advisable. Use git for this