# Remove invalid reference from sys.path

Tags: python-3.x, unc, sys.path

While trying to set up a virtual environment on a network drive ( my previous post: [Setting up virtual environment on network drive for Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60607757/11792868)), I added "WORKON_HOME: \NAS\Coding" as an environmental variable and value. After it was explained to me that this wouldn't work, I removed the WORKON_HOME variable. However, it seems that the value is still being stored somewhere because I keep getting this error message when I try to run scripts.

```
\\NAS\Coding
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.719]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

This is the output from running a script to print sys.path.

```
['\\\\NAS\\Coding', 'C:\\Python\\python38.zip', 'C:\\Python\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python\\lib',
 'C:\\Python', 'C:\\Users\\USER NAME\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Python\\lib\\site- 
 packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

I looked through all of the environmental variables and I don't see a reference to it.

I also tried to remove it with this simple script but it doesn't seem to do anything (at least not permanently).

```
import sys

sys.path.remove('\\\\NAS\\Coding')
```

I also tried running this directly in the terminal but I get this.

```
C:\Windows>C:\Python\python.exe -c "import sys"

C:\Windows>C:\Python\python.exe -c "sys.path.remove('\\\\NAS\\Coding')"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
```

Any ideas how I can remove this directory listing?

Comment: `list.remove` just removes an item in place if found so it won't visible do anything until you print the list out to check it's gone... In the second example, you're running a python interpreter to import something, it runs that and exits, then you run another one to try to use `sys`, which isn't imported... your second one you'd want to run as `python.exe -c "import sys; sys.path.remove('\\\\NAS\\Coding')"` - but ultimately, you need to think your environment variable `PYTHONPATH` or `PATH` themselves

Comment: @JonClements I looked through all of the `PATH` values but didn't find any reference to the NAS folder and there is no `PYTHONPATH` variable. Do I need to set it?


Also, I guess it should not come as a surprise that `python.exe -c "import sys; sys.path.remove('\\\\NAS\\Coding')"` did not work.